# Getting exception while reading data from HDF5 file using hyperslab if I set Offset non zero

Tags: c#, .net, hdf5

Here I am trying to read part of data from hdf5 file. I am able to write and read whole data in a dataset, but now I want to read part of data for that I am using 'Hyperslab' it throws exception

```
'H5D.read: 
Failed to read data to data set 5000002 with status -1'
```

**Now it is giving me 5000000 error for the same condition**

at line

```
H5D.read(dataSetIdTO, typeId, memspaceid, filespaceid,
         new H5PropertyListId(new H5P.Template()), new H5Array<int>(readDataBack));
```

**EDIT:
This exception throws only when offset is not 0 (zero), If I set offset[0]=0 then it works fine**

My code

```
//Open hdf5 file
H5FileId fileId = H5F.open("myCSharp.h5", H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);

long[] offset = new long[1];
offset[0] = 1;

long[] count = new long[1];
count[0] = 500;

//Open group
H5GroupId groupId = H5G.open(fileId, "GroupName");

// Open the data set.
H5DataSetId dataSetIdTO = H5D.open(groupId, "DataSetName");

// Get space id from our data set
H5DataSpaceId filespaceid = H5D.getSpace(dataSetIdTO);

//Create new space to read hyperslab in memory
H5DataSpaceId memspaceid = H5S.create_simple(1, count);

//select hyperslabs in dataspace
H5S.selectHyperslab(memspaceid, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, offset, count);
H5S.selectHyperslab(filespaceid, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, offset, count);

//array to read data
int[] readDataBack = new int[500];

H5DataTypeId typeId = new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT);

//Read data from dataset 
// * I got Exception here*
H5D.read(dataSetIdTO, typeId, memspaceid, filespaceid,
          new H5PropertyListId(new H5P.Template()), new H5Array<int>(readDataBack));
```

Comment: You can leave comments to improve my question.

Comment: What are dimensions of your H5 file?

Comment: rank is 1 and dim[0] is 100000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so much hard I got to know why that was happening. Here I was creating memory space equal to count which should be greater than count given to hyperslab.

```
//Create new space to read hyperslab in memory
H5DataSpaceId memspaceid = H5S.create_simple(1, count);
```

Instead of this I need to make new long array

```
//delclar long array for memory space dims
long[] memSpaceDims = new long[1];
memSpaceDims[0] = 5001; //it should be greater than count[0]

//Create new space to read hyperslab in memory
H5DataSpaceId memspaceid = H5S.create_simple(1, memSpaceDims);
```